# Using Mockito spy to mock a method without specifying the exact argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a use case where I have to test the real method which calls a method inside. This inner method has to be mocked. For instance,

```
Class Sample {
   boolean method(Foo foo) {
     return innerMethod(new Goo(foo));
   }
}
```

So I want to do the following.

```
Sample sample = Mockito.spy(new Sample());
Foo foo = new Foo();
doReturn(false).when(sample).innerMethod(new Goo(foo));

assertEquals(false, sample.method(foo));
```

The problem is, I suppose, the inner method is never mocked since the arguments `Goo` are not the same objects. How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Use a matcher: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3

Comment: Why do you care that it call an internal method? It seems to me that you're testing your internal implementation instead of the behaviour. Why don't you just write a test that given a Foo in some state, it should return false/true ?

Comment: @JBNizet that was very helpful. Used `Mockito.eq` and `Mockito.argThat` with a extension of `ArgumentMatcher<T>`.

Comment: @blank It is one of those managers that does a lot of things. It doesn't make sense to mock a 100 different things to test a method. Hence, mocking parts of the function using spy. And needless to say, what you see is just a minimal example of the use case and not the actual function :)

Comment: That is called partial mocking, it's wrong. You'd better refactor this to avoid partial mocking and prefer a design that use composition. Also answer of @BetaRide is technically correct you should validate it!

Comment: Agree with @Brice if you have to mock a 100 things to test a method your class is doing way too much and needs to be refactored. http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Matcher.any()` method.

```
doReturn(false).when(sample).innerMethod(Matcher.any(Goo.class));
```